# Break a table between pages AND rotate it sideways

Tags: tables, page-breaking, rotating

I have a long table with a lot of columns, so I want it to be landscape. The problem is I can't figure out how to have both a rotated table, and automatic break between pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work well for me:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu}{X}
\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\blindtext\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I have only used the     tabu package because I like using X columns from
    tabularx in my table and the package has a good implementation of that

Comment: This does indeed do the trick. I wonder though why lscape rotates the whole page, is it possible to bypass that, is there a reason for this?